# Connect to SQL Data Warehouse from HDInsight OnDemand

Tags: scala, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory, mssql-jdbc, azure-synapse

I'm trying to read/write data to an Azure SQL Data Warehouse from a spark on demand HDInsight cluster.

I can do this from a normal HDInsight spark cluster by [using a script action to install the jdbc driver](https://gist.github.com/CBurbidge/c05ae3829204bdcd545ab662d7cd7d39) but I don't think it's possible to run script actions on the on demand clusters.

I've tried

- Copying the files from %user%.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\mssql-jdbc\6.2.2.jre8 up to blob storage in a folder called jars next to where the built spark code is.
- including the driver dependency in the built jar file

Both of these led to a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

I'm not too familiar with scala/maven/JVM/etc so not sure what else to try or include in this SO question.

Scala code i'm trying to run is

```
val sqlContext = SparkSession.builder().appName("GenerateEventsSql").getOrCreate()

val jdbcSqlConnStr = "jdbc:sqlserver://someserver.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=myDW;user=admin;password=XXXX;"

val tableName = "dbo.SomeTable"

val allTableData = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")
                    .options(Map(
                      "driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
                      "url" -> jdbcSqlConnStr, "dbtable" -> tableName)
                    )
  .load()
```

Comment: which class exactly cannot be found?

Answer (score 0):

Jars on Blob storage folder are not accessible to the Class path of HDinsight spark job. You need to copy the jar files to the local host for example /tmp/jars/xyz.jar and mention the same in Spark-submit command.

For e.g.

```
nohup spark-submit --jars /tmp/jars/xyz.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I don't have a way of accessing the azure account I was using so I can't try it out.

I was originally looking for a way to do this with HDInsight OnDemand service and i'm not sure that running the code above would be possible in such a setup.